# react native: change style property on scroll scrollview

Tags: react-native

I have a view (flex: 0) above a scrollview (flex: 1). When I scroll down on the scrollview (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 0), I want to change the border bottom color of the top view.

Current code:

```
const Screen = (props) => {
  // ...

  const [bottom, setBottom] = useState(0);

  const scrollE = (event) => {
    setBottom(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 0 ? 1 : 0);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 0, borderBottomWidth: bottom, borderBottomColor: 'black' }}>
        <Text>HEADER</Text>
      </View>
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} onScroll={scrollE} scrollEventThrottle={16}>
        // ... scrollview content
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

It seems like my screen is flashing when scrolling. I **think** it has something to do with the re-renders everytime my border state changes. I tried changing it with use ref to this, but this does not work either:

```
const Screen = (props) => {
  // ...

  const bottom = useRef(0);

  const scrollE = (event) => {
    bottom.current = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 0 ? 1 : 0;
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 0, borderBottomWidth: bottom.current, borderBottomColor: 'black' }}>
        <Text>HEADER</Text>
      </View>
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} onScroll={scrollE} scrollEventThrottle={16}>
        // ... scrollview content
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I do not need a "sticky" header that resizes, I only want the border bottom width to change.

Comment: Where did you pass bottom (ref)?

Comment: Nowhere. Do I need to pass it somewhere? You can use useRef without assigning it to an object I think...

Comment: When you describe ref `const ref = useRef();` and pass it into some component `<Component ref={ref} ... />`, **then ref.current** gives you reference to this component.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't need the reference to a component in this situation... you can also store values in a useRef constant without losing the value on re-renders.

Comment: Can you give me a snack url? I'll try to help you.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@samleurs/scroll-bottom

Comment: I created my [snack](https://snack.expo.io/DDOYK6duL). Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225626/discussion-between-yesterday-and-j-doe).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with animated API, hope this helps

```
 const Screen = (props) => {
  const scrollY= new Animated.Value(0)

  const scrollE = (event) => {
   Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }],{ useNativeDriver: true })
  };

const bottom = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 10],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
})

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 0, borderBottomWidth: bottom, borderBottomColor: 'black' }}>
        <Text>HEADER</Text>
      </View>
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} onScroll={scrollE} scrollEventThrottle={16}>
        // ... scrollview content
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
```